# How to do smooth bouncing animation using JavaFX transitions?

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

I want to do an expanding circle animation. I'm changing radius from 17.5 to 25 and want it's edges to bounce a bit before the end of transition. So far I only figured out how to do simple linear animations:

```
class CircleTranslation extends Transition {

    protected Circle circle;
    protected double startRadius;
    protected double radiusDiff;

    public CircleTranslation(Circle circle, double newRadius, Duration duration) {
        setCycleDuration(duration);
        this.circle = circle;
        this.startRadius = circle.getRadius();
        this.radiusDiff = newRadius - startRadius;
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double fraction) {
        circle.setRadius( startRadius + ( radiusDiff * fraction ) );
    }
}
```

How can I do a bouncing animation with JavaFX? I'm looking for something that will act like Elastic or Bounce effect of [Greensock Visualizer](https://greensock.com/docs/Easing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a interpolator that uses several quadratic functions to interpolate the value:

```
CircleTranslation transition = ...
Interpolator interpolator = new Interpolator() {

    /**
     * Calculate value of quadratic function with roots sx, ex and
     * maximum of maxVal at x=t.
     */
    private double val(double t, double sx, double ex, double maxVal) {
        double v = (t - sx) * (ex - t);
        double max = (ex - sx) / 2;
        return maxVal * v / (max * max);
    }

    @Override
    protected double curve(double t) {
        double x;
        if (t <= 0.37) {
            x = val(t, -0.37, 0.37, 1);
        } else if (t <= 0.73) {
            x = val(t, 0.37, 0.73, 0.25);
        } else if (t <= 0.91) {
            x = val(t, 0.73, 0.91, 0.08);
        } else {
            x = val(t, 0.91, 1, 0.03);
        }
        return 1 - x;
    }

};
transition.setInterpolator(interpolator);
...
```

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read about how to calculate that? It works, but I just want to understand how you did it, looks quite complicated and interesting

Comment: @Alyona `f(x) = a * (x - r1) * (x - r2)` is the formula for quadratic polynomials assuming there are roots. Since the curve is symetric the extreme value is reached for `x = (r1+r2) / 2`. Using these facts you can come up with `val` method. The `curve` method simply "puts multiple parabolas next to each other" to achieve the curve  similar to the one in the link.